# MySQL: SELECT (column == 'value') return result of type “LONGLONG” instead of BOOL

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

When I do

```
SELECT (column1 == 1) AS isOne FROM table1;
```

I'd expect to have a result set with a column of type BOOL, a.k.a. TINYINT(1). 
Unfortunately, I receive a "LONGLONG".

Here's an experiment.

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Launching the MySQL prompt with extra type info `--column-type-info`:

```
mysql> select id, id=1 as isOne  from orders;
Field   1:  `id`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `reson_it`
Table:      `orders`
Org_table:  `orders`
Type:       LONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     11
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL PRI_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NUM PART_KEY

Field   2:  `isOne`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG <--------------- WTF Why is this not a boolean/tinyint(1) ???
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM


+----+-------+
| id | isOne |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I see this LONGLONG type in the "isOne" result field. Why does this happen?

I'm using **MySQL 5.6.27** on mac (installed with homebrew).

Comment: Oh Long Johnson. Sorry I couldn't hold myself.

Comment: Does typecasting it to a boolean help?

Comment: Your create table does not show any bool or tinyint fields.

Comment: Btw, longlong stands for bigint.

Comment: @Tuure can you propose a working query with bool/tinyint type cast? I'm having difficulties: my starting point is this `SELECT (column1== 'val1') AS isVal1 FROM table1`

Comment: You could try: `SELECT CAST((column1== 'val1') AS BOOL) AS isVal1 FROM table1` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: Found out this works: `CONVERT(column1 = 'val1', BINARY(1))` note the single equals and convert instead of cast (cast is for strings).  Unfortunately it comes out with YET ANOTHER crazy type similar to BOOL that is not BOOL: VARBINARY(1). 
MySQL types are a lost cause. That's why it's so popular with dynamic languages users. BTW, everything is fine with Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this happen?

Because that's how MySQL does it.

The wire protocol does not allow columns to have different data types from row-to-row in a result set, (nor would sanity) so the server has to decide up front what data type each column will be, particularly when output columns are derived and don't come directly from a single specific table/column (because, in that case, the output column's definition is already known... by definition, you might say... the source column's definition).

The behavior you observe may or may not be clearly documented -- if it is, I'm not finding it off hand -- but it can be inferred from the fact that a column that is the result of adding two `TINYINT` columns together, or even adding a literal 0 to a `TINYINT`, will in fact also be a `BIGINT` (longlong) -- even though it theoretically needs to be nothing larger than a `SMALLINT` or `TINYINT` -- depending on the query -- but MySQL always uses 64 bit values for internal operations and for derived integer output columns.

That last part *is* documented, and it seems reasonable to extrapolate it to this case, too.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

The manual states (somewhere) that integer-like expressions (including `BIT`, `BOOL`, etc) are done in `BIGINT`, decimal-like expressions are done in a certain precision, divisions are done to `div_precision_increment` decimal places, floating operations are done in `DOUBLE`.

There are also rules about `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED`, and there have been bugs over the years about the handling of such.  For example, what does it mean to subtract two `UNSIGNED` values, especially if the first is smaller?

Since the number `1` comes out as the string `'1'` regardless of `LONGLONG` or whatever, it does not matter much.

Perhaps `--column-type-info` is more confusing than helpful?